# move prototype cells down page in iOS

Tags: ios

I've just started iOS development and have been making a tab bar app. I have a table view and prototype cells to display some news items. Is there a way to stop the prototype cells filling the whole screen view. Currently mine starts right at the top of the page. But I'd prefer it started lower. I've seen other apps like Instagram and Twitter for instance have almost a banner across the app at the top and maybe an inbox icon. I wouldn't be opposed to implementing this either. But I'm unsure how to go about it currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableView`, like many other — but not all — views, has a `contentInset` property which you can use to create an unfilled zone around the content. If your table view is full screen and you have a status bar or a navigation bar then it's reasonably likely that UIKit has set something to it automatically.

But supposing there were no status bar or navigation bar then you'd do something like:

```
_tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetMake(80.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

That would create an 80pt blank area before the cell content.

Documentation: [`UIEdgeInsetMake`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIEdgeInsetsMake), [`contentInset`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentInset) (which is inherited from `UIScrollView`).

Comment: Thanks Tommy, what would be the best place to place this code, is in any particular method, apologies for the simplicity of this question.

Comment: If it's always the same offset then probably `viewDidLoad`. Otherwise maybe `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.